# Unable to make directory and put files in it while uploading picture using php?

Tags: php

I am currently having problem uploading picture to directory, 
here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
//Check whether the user has uploaded a profile pic or not
  $check_pic = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT profile_pic FROM users2 WHERE username='$user'");
  $get_pic_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_pic);
  $profile_pic_db = $get_pic_row['profile_pic'];
  if ($profile_pic_db == "") {
  $profile_pic = "images/default_pic.jpg";
  }
  else
  {
  $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profile_pic_db;
  }
  //Profile Image upload script
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   mkdir("/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

   if (file_exists("/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]))
   {
    echo @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]." Already exists";
   }
   else
   {
    move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

   }
  }
  else
  {
      $msg5 =  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

and here is my  html code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="profilepic" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Change Profile Photo">
</form>
```

where $user is the username of the user signed in, and my database connection is all working fine: I am able to update my `profile_pic` query in database, but not uploading it to the userdata folder. I am using a godaddy account, is there any configuration changes needed in my `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here

```
mkdir("/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");
```

This is trying to make a folder in the root of the system, which you almost certainly don't have access too. You probably want to create it relative to your site, so something like:

```
mkdir(__DIR__."/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");
```

might solve the problem.

Additionally if the parent folders do not exist, you can use the third parameter of `mkdir` to create them. By default `mkdir` only creates the last directory so if the one's before it don't exist it'll fail.

Comment: the random directory is now coming up, but what about moving file there in move_uploaded_file function?

Comment: Did you add `__DIR__` to the front of the directory there too?

Comment: Rather than recreating the string twice you could do `$dir = __DIR__."/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";` followed by `mkdir($dir);` and `move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],$dir.'/'.$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);`

Comment: As a side issue, you should be aware, allowing users to upload into a directory that is publicly visible through your web server is very dangerous. They can then navigate to the file which may not be an image, but might be `deleteAllTheThings.php` :)

Comment: still, it is not uploading it to directory, any solutions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75298/discussion-between-rahul-kapoor-and-danielm).